# How can I easily duplicate the trello style of drag and drop of cards? (Kanban style app)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, trello

I'm building a web app that uses a similar drag and drop metaphor that trello has for moving cards around by dragging and dropping cards from one list to another.

How can I do this?

Comment: Another possible solution is this [React/Redux example on Github](https://github.com/web-pal/react-trello-board)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

An upgraded version built upon [Brad Parks-s answer right on this very page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212605/how-can-i-easily-duplicate-the-trello-style-of-drag-and-drop-of-cards#answer-21212606) featuring even more indent and an awesome tilt-towards-drag-direction effect as demonstrated on [this jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/FVyS2/).

Different bits in JavaScript follow the comments:

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    handle: ".portlet-header",
    cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.addClass('tilt');
        // Start monitoring tilt direction
        tilt_direction(ui.item);
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.removeClass("tilt");
        // Unbind temporary handlers and excess data
        $("html").unbind('mousemove', ui.item.data("move_handler"));
        ui.item.removeData("move_handler");
    }
});

// Monitor tilt direction and switch between classes accordingly
function tilt_direction(item) {
    var left_pos = item.position().left,
        move_handler = function (e) {
            if (e.pageX >= left_pos) {
                item.addClass("right");
                item.removeClass("left");
            } else {
                item.addClass("left");
                item.removeClass("right");
            }
            left_pos = e.pageX;
        };
    $("html").bind("mousemove", move_handler);
    item.data("move_handler", move_handler);
}
```

CSS modifications for different tilt degrees

```
.tilt.right {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
}
.tilt.left {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

Comment: How to serialize the div tags/portlet at the end and see which list it belongs to... ?

Comment: please make a new question on the site and elaborate and generalize a bit what is your goal

Answer (score 21):

The following example uses jQuery UI "sortable" and CSS3 to do the Trello "tilt" drag effect.

You can [check it out here as a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVta5/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Portlets</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>

  .tilt {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  }

  body {
    min-width: 520px;
  }

  .column {
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .portlet {
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
  }
  .portlet-header {
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
  }
  .portlet-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
  }
  .portlet-content {
    padding: 0.4em;
  }
  .portlet-placeholder {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    height: 50px;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(onPageLoad);

  function onPageLoad()
  {
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".column",
      handle: ".portlet-header",
      cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
      start: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.addClass('tilt');
      },
      stop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.removeClass('tilt');
      }
    });

    $( ".portlet" )
      .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
      .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

    $( ".portlet-toggle" ).click(function() {
      var icon = $( this );
      icon.toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick" );
      icon.closest( ".portlet" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });
  }
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Shopping</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Images</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are already providing a working example in fiddle why not to try to highlight the key aspects of your intentions in code and reduce the "just dumped the whole html page"-look-and-feel of your answer :D

Comment: well... because i didn't write most of it... It's really just a 90% copy of the jQuery UI Sortable demo [found here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets), with an additional javascript event to do the tilt effect. Now when people google "trello card effect javascript", they'll get this sample, which is more than I got ;-)

Comment: Please add an explanation of the solution.